# Windows 8.1 putting hard drive into sleep mode

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, sleep

I have SSD with operating system and operating program which I use daily - it's small 120GB disc - and two 1TB HDD where I saved full-day work. I use HDD two times per day but they are not going on a sleep mode automatically. Is there any possible to put HDD into sleep mode in "one-click" in windows 8.1?

Comment: Sure, but what is most likely preventing Windows from going into sleep mode is another piece of software, in my experience the Steam Client prevents Windows from going into sleep mode. Anyways what I have done is to make sure that Steam is closed, then I set the computer to go to sleep after so many minutes (I think 15). I set the main power button to put the computer to sleep as well when pressed. If I am feeling inpatient I just do it through the menu.

You can read the following article.
http://lifehacker.com/5924010/how-to-find-out-whats-keeping-your-computer-from-going-to-sleep

Comment: What is another problem?

Comment: Because I consider about preventing HDD (with unused data - hibernate data) from going into sleep mode, not windows. I have OS on SSD and this drive are ready all-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem there is two tools:

- [RevoSleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/)
- [quietHDD](https://sites.google.com/site/quiethdd/)

First tool is full of hdd option for windows 7 and older, fortunately this is good solution under windows 8.1. Second is good for noise reduce.

At this time, I cannot find better tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Advance Power Settings, under the Hard Disk dropdown you can select when to make Windows automatically turn off the hard disks. I don't know if a program like that exists, but I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard to create.

Comment: In advaced mode I have Hard Drive in general, I have turn off option for all drive. I  don't have separated option for SSD, HDD1,HDD2.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of [revoSleep](https://www.meinfach.net/revosleep/) which now works fine also on Windows 8 and 10 and newer.